# Parse URL in SQL Server table to extract Key and Value Pairs

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a URL field.  It contains random urls from customer sites.  I want to extract the key and value from those urls that have a querystring.  For example if I have:

> [http://www.tigerdirect.ca/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=2580461&sku=B69-1412&SRCCODE=CANEMBP004&cm_mmc=Email-*-Retro-*-CANEMBP004-_-viewed](http://www.tigerdirect.ca/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=2580461&sku=B69-1412&SRCCODE=CANEMBP004&cm_mmc=Email-_-Retro-_-CANEMBP004-_-viewed)

I need the stored procedure to return a Key and Value in the result.

```
EdpNo=2580461
sku=B69-1412
SRCCODE=CANEMBP004
cm_mmc=Email-_-Retro-_-CANEMBP004-_-viewed
```

Where `EdpN`o is the Key and `2580461` is the value in the first example

I have looked at a few user defined functions but they all work on passing in just one url at a time where I need to scan the url field in a table.

Perhaps I just don't know how to use them, so any insight on what I have or perhaps how it can be restructured would be much appreciated.

UDF:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitQueryString] (@s varchar(8000))
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
    WITH splitter_cte AS (
      SELECT CHARINDEX('&', @s) as pos, 0 as lastPos
      UNION ALL
      SELECT CHARINDEX('&', @s, pos + 1), pos
      FROM splitter_cte
      WHERE pos > 0
      ),
    pair_cte AS (
    SELECT chunk,
           CHARINDEX('=', chunk) as pos
    FROM (
        SELECT SUBSTRING(@s, lastPos + 1,
                         case when pos = 0 then 80000
                         else pos - lastPos -1 end) as chunk
        FROM splitter_cte) as t1
  )
    SELECT substring(chunk, 0, pos) as keyName,
           substring(chunk, pos+1, 8000) as keyValue
    FROM pair_cte
);
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: You probably need to look into the `APPLY` operator for working with the whole table at once. `SELECT splits.keyname, splits.keyvalue FROM <table> CROSS APPLY [dbo].[SplitQueryString](<field_name>) AS splits` is the kind of syntax you're looking for

Comment: use regex to parse the tsql code.

Comment: You may already realize this, but performance on this kind of operation will be poor.  SQL Server will perform a table scan on your table and parse every URL using your UDF (which, in turn, uses an iterative/recursive query).  If your table is large, this will take a long time to do using SQL Server.  If you have the ability to do this with a CLR procedure, you way want to consider that route as an option.

Comment: @DeadZone thanks, I am looking at another approach that does not rely on SQL Server table scan...a javascript function to pull the key value and then I will store that in a table.